# jQuery, How to target very specific selectors?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Apologies if this has been asked already, I can't find the answer in the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/).

How would I select all `.tooltip` classes which have a `[title]` attribute, and the `[title]` attribute is not empty?

In other words, select these:

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="YES">Foo</a>
<span class="tooltip" title="YES">Bar</span>
```

But not these:

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="">Empty title attribute.</a>
<span class="tooltip">No title attribute.</span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this selector:

```
.tooltip[title]:not([title=""])
```

Comment: It's so easy when you know how. =) Thanks once again, Gumbo.

Comment: I've found that this also seems to work, although it's possible the plugin I'm using does some filtering, too: `$( '.tooltip[title!=""]' )`

Comment: @Jeff: Nice, didn’t know that attribute selector since it’s not part of CSS 3. But mine is CSS 3 compliant.

Comment: @Gumbo: What part of my selector has anything to do with CSS 3? I think what it says is "all .tooltip classes with a title attribute not equal to an empty string."

Comment: @Jeff: There is no attribute selector like `[attr!="value"]`. The negation needs to be expressed with `:not()`: `:not([attr="value"])`.